# Django Book tree base model

Tags: django, model, tree

I'd like to know if is possible to do a book base model. Every category has many subcategories with the same name. For ex: Book 1 has section 1, section 2, etc. Every section chapter 1, chapter 2 and so on. Which is the best way to do the structure?

Comment: This question is rather broad, so I am recommending it is put on hold.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this way by defining models and using `one-to-many` relationships.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    bookName = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Section(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sectionName = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Chapter(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chapterName = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Topic(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    topicName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: A suggestion, is it necessary for the **Topic** model to have a field **section**? The chapter field alone does make it under a section right?

Comment: @AjmalNoushad, It is not necessary but I will recommend you to put it, coz later it will be easy for you, When you will need to chain all these.

Comment: @MariaC, Did you understand? Is it ok?

Comment: I'm going to try now, but I think that I undertand, thank you! I'll tell you the results after I try.